# Number of columns highlighted

Tags: gvim

As I am moving from Windows to Linux for my development machine, I have noticed a difference in vim between the Windows version and the Linux version. The windows will show you the number of highlighted columns at the bottom of the screen where the Linux version does not (or at least how I have it configured). I have looked at the differences between the two settings, and nothing sticks out. What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: What is "number of highlighted columns"? Do you think the position of the cursor in the bottom right?

Comment: You are missing a `:set showcmd` setting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After opening vim, execute this:

```
:set showcmd
```

Or, add this to your vimrc for permanent solution:

```
set showcmd
```

From the help docs, `:h showcmd`:

```
'showcmd' 'sc'      boolean (Vim default: on, Vi default: off)
            global
Show (partial) command in the last line of the screen.  Set this
option off if your terminal is slow.
In Visual mode the size of the selected area is shown:
- When selecting characters within a line, the number of characters.
  If the number of bytes is different it is also displayed: "2-6"
  means two characters and six bytes.
- When selecting more than one line, the number of lines.
- When selecting a block, the size in screen characters:
  {lines}x{columns}.
```

Comment: If the answer is correct, then consider marking it correct for future references.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, Windows has a default vimrc file called _vimrc. Most GNU/Linux distros do not have a default vimrc file. Look into the _vimrc file on Windows to change any options you want.

Comment: I looked over the default _vimrc on my Windows machine, and there is no reference to the showcmd at all plus when I perform the :set command again no reference so guessing this is compile option that is enabled on the Windows builds.

Comment: What do you mean most GNU/Linux distros don't have a default vimrc? Of course there is a default vimrc. Look at your ~/.vimrc